# Xcache can't reload php opcode when source code changed

Tags: php, opcode, xcache

Can Xcache or other php opcode cachers auto-reload php opcode when php source code has changed?

Answer (score 2):

Most opcode caches have a configuration setting to determine whether they should refresh their cached entry for a script that has been changed. Typically this would be set to happen automatically in a development environment; but there's an overhead to doing the check, so it's normally disabled in a production environment.

xcache has the ttl setting, 0 for a production environment, else refresh after x seconds

```
xcache.ttl 
    seconds Ttl (Time To Live) value for the php entry (cached opcodes of a file), 0=forever.
```